# Get The Step Name & Number Of A CucumberJs Step & Set The Result Of A Step

Tags: javascript, bdd, cucumberjs

Is it possible to get the following information from cucumber.js

1. From a JavaScript step get the current step number
2. From a JavaScript step get the current step name
3. From a JavaScript Step "set" the step result

I have cases whereby I would like to override the result provided by framework.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I posted this question on Github too and I got some useful suggestions on how to get Step Number, Step Name & "setting" the Step Result.

Thread can be found here @

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/719